# What is the probability that at least 2 of the 4 end balls are the same colour?

Tags: probability

There are 2 identical sets of balls

Each of them has: 3 blue balls, 2 red balls and one white ball.

Each of these sets is placed in a line.

What is the probability that at least 2 of the 4 end balls are the same colour?

I know how to work out the probability that not more than 2 of the four will be the same. $(\frac{4!}{2!})(\frac{6!}{3!2!})+(\frac{4!}{3!})(\frac{6!}{3!2!})+(\frac{5!}{2!‌​2!})^2 +(\frac{5!}{2!2!})^2 =2260$  and you divide that by $3600=(\frac{6!}{3!2!})$  but the solution for this one said 1 is the answer and I just don't know how to approach it

Comment: Did you try to read some how-to-ask advice on this site?

Comment: I know how to work out the probability that not more than 2 of the four will be the same. $(\frac{4!}{2!})(\frac{6!}{3!2!})+(\frac{4!}{3!})(\frac{6!}{3!2!})+(\frac{5!}{2!2!})^2+(\frac{5!}{2!2!})^2 = 2260$ and you divide that by $3600 = (\frac{6!}{3!2!})$ but the solution for this one said 1 is the answer and I just don't know how to approach it

Comment: Why not placing your comment in your question? That will make clear that you have tried things and people will be more willing to answer instead of downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint: Try to compose a configuration where there are no two end balls of the same color.

Comment: Oh I see. It's impossible because there would need to be 4 colours, therefore the probability is one for the fact that at least 2 must be the same colour because every case must have at least that